# Transform json input with logstash filter

Tags: filter, logstash

I am getting input for logstash through a Kafka pipe, which works fine. The most relevant data in that stream are in the following format

```
{data: [
    {
        name: 'fieldname1',
        value: 'value1'
    },
    {
        name: 'fieldname2',
        value: 'value2'
    },
    ..
]}
```

For the use in Kibana, I need to transform that to

```
{data: {
    'fieldname1': 'value1',
    'fieldname2': 'value2'
}}
```

Is there a simpler way of doing that besides the ruby filter plugin?

Comment: It might be doable with the kv filter, but it would be extremely complicated, so I don't see any simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baudsp is right. Unless your data array has a fixed size, there is no way to do that because logstash does not have the capabilities of iterating.

Alternatively you could write your own transform plugin that could do that, but this might be overkill (and is essentially also just ruby code).